# ZXing QR Code in Silverlight Web

Tags: c#, silverlight, webcam, zxing

I'm having some trouble using ZXing in silverlight.

I'm using this ZXing port: http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/

My proejct is able to get the video feed from the webcam, but I'm stuck at this line.

This is how i get the feed:

```
CaptureSource _capture = new CaptureSource();
        _capture.VideoCaptureDevice = CaptureDeviceConfiguration.GetDefaultVideoCaptureDevice();
        videoBrush = new VideoBrush();
        videoBrush.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
        videoBrush.SetSource(_capture);
        webcam.Fill = videoBrush;
        if (CaptureDeviceConfiguration.AllowedDeviceAccess||CaptureDeviceConfiguration.RequestDeviceAccess())
        {
            try
            {
                _capture.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception E)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(E.Message);
            }
        }


LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(,webcam.Width, webcam.Height);
```

It says, that says that it need a byte array, the "rbgRawBytes".

I got a videobrush which contains the webcam stream, i think :)
and i got the webcam rectangle that displays the output.

Comment: Which silverlight port of zxing do you use? Please post a more complete code snippet which shows your image source (the videobrush) and the concrete types.

Comment: sorry about that, i've just updated it :)

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the RGBLuminanceSource instead of the Bitmap LS? You can easily extract a bitmap from your CaptureSource/VideoBrush and then feed it to the BitmapLuminanceSource constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the method CaptureImageAsync and the event CaptureImageCompleted. In the event handler you get a WriteableBitmap within the event arguments. The WriteableBitmap is a captured image from the webcam. Use the WriteableBitmap instance directly with the method Decode of the BarcodeReader class. Don't do it manually by using RGBLuminanceSource.

Here is a good sample how you can use CaptureImageAsync and CaptureImageCompleted:
http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/FaceLight--Silverlight-4-Real-Time-Face-Detection